# How can i improve performance of my application?

Tags: c#

I have three different function which i call based on the condition. When data is lesser my application performance is good. However, i have around 11000 rows of data my application taking 1-2 hour to complete the process.

I have some logic written in my functions which filters data and add into collection. Is there is any way i can improve the performance of my application using multi-threading or parallel processing. so that my function runs parallel and performance get improved.

I created a sample of my requirement below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] AllData = new String[7];
        AllData[0] = "1";
        AllData[1] = "2";
        AllData[2] = "3";
        AllData[3] = "1";
        AllData[4] = "2";
        AllData[5] = "3";
        AllData[6] = "1";
        for (int i = 0; i < AllData.Length; i++)
        {
            CommonFunction(AllData[i]);
        }
    }
    private void CommonFunction(String AllData)
    {
        if (AllData == "1")
        {
            Function1(1);
        }
        else if (AllData == "2")
        {
            Function2(2);
        }
        else
        {
            Function3(3);
        }
    }
    private void Function1(int ID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    private void Function2(int ID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    private void Function3(int ID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it will give you error saying **array out of bound**, as size of array is 3 and you are inserting 7 strings to it

Comment: also `AllData[i].ToString()` here `.ToString()` is useless as `AllData` is a `String` array

Comment: I think it's better to use [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for this kind of question.

Comment: Performance is the least of your troubles, getting it to compile should be your first step. Tips don't convert data types when its not needed. Look up what a `switch` statement does

Comment: @SeM - no, codereview is not for performance questions.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here, calling 3 empty functions 11000 times won't take more than a few ms.

Comment: @bommelding moreover, I assume any decent compiler would even skip them

Comment: A quick search of [how to parallel for c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) will show you how to change your button1_Click function

Comment: @bommelding yes, it is. Well you do not need to title your question like - _"How can I improve my performance"_, but you can ask like - _"<<some part>> needs improvment"_, and tag your question with `performance` tag.

Comment: i cannot put my original code here. That's why i just put an example.

Comment: Also i need help on multi-threading and parallel processing

Comment: But that example is way too weak and simplified. Go and read about setting up a [mcve].

Comment: Still what is needed is a better explannation of what is your performance issue. Perhaps some simple Stopwatch would help a lot . perhaps the issue is in Function1, Function2, Function3

Comment: I just want to know can i run the Function 1, Function 2 and Function 3 parallely. So that i dont have to wait for function code to be execute process should run paralley

Comment: Basicaly you got to choose either you want us to address performance issue and it lack an [MCVE] and a lot of information. Or you fail to find information on parallel for and it's a dupe.

Comment: If it takes 1-2h for 11k rows, then maybe just try with 1000 `"1"`, then with 1000 `"2"` and with 1000 `"3"` to know which one of your 3 functions is taking so much time to run, then post that function here so we can tell you why

Comment: Also you wrote *filters data and add into collection*. Do they add data into the same collection? Is the order of insertion important? If so, then maybe parallel processing isn't what you're looking for

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sequential `for` loop, you can try to use `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllData.Length; i++)
{
    CommonFunction(AllData[i].ToString());
}
```

can be converted to

```
Parallel.ForEach(AllData, someData => 
{
    CommonFunction(someData);
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what the fuzz if all about since the OP asked 'Is there is any way i can improve the performance of my application using multi-threading or parallel processing?' and the only thing that those can be applied to based on the code posted is the `for` loop in the `button1_Click()` method.